# The middle variable in the Chain Rule

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I often see people introduce a middle variable z to compute the derivative dy/dx using the Chain Rule: dy/dx=dy/dz*dz/dx. I wonder if z should satisfy some conditions. If z can be any variable, e.g., an independent variable that has nothing to do with y and x, then dy/dz=0, dz/dx=0, so dy/dx=dy/dz*dz/dx=0*0=0, which is obviously wrong. I read in some books that the condition is y is differentiable to z and z is differentiable to x. But this is not true as seen in this example.

Comment: The chain rule isn't about “variables”, it's about **functions**. If $y=f(z)$ where $z=g(x)$, then $y=f(g(x))$, and the derivative of that equals etc.

Comment: Yes. I come from the field of computer science, where variable is the synonyms of function in some cases.

Comment: You probably meant to put the word “function” in there somewhere? But anyway, to talk about the chain rule you need two (differentiable) functions $f$ and $g$, so that you can form the composite function $f \circ g$. Saying that $z$ is an independent variable that has nothing to do with $y$ and $x$ is a rather meaningless statement in this context.

Comment: Starting with $f$ and $g$, you can form $h=f \circ g$ and compute its derivative using the chain rule. And conversely, if you start with a function $h$ you might be able to find $f$ and $g$ such that $h=f \circ g$, which amounts to what you call introducing a middle variable $z$, but what you do then is finding *functions* $f$ and $g$ with the crucial property that $h=f \circ g$, you don't just write down a symbol $z$ without meaning and call it a “variable”.

Comment: I think I can use an example to make it clear. Suppose you compute the derivative of  Frank's weight(y) to his age(x), you may introduce another unrelated middle variable: Franks's father's weight(z).

Comment: Well, in that case we have $y=h(x)$, Frank's weight depends on his age. But with your choice of $z$ there are no functions $y=f(z)$ and $z=g(x)$ such that $h(x)=f(g(x))$, so even talking about $dy/dz$ and $dz/dx$ is meaningless. (It's not that these derivatives are zero, they are not even defined to begin with. What *functions* are you taking derivatives of?)

Comment: I don't know the specific form of f(z) and g(x) as I do not know the specific form of h(x). What I know is y is not affected by the variation of z(so dy/dz=0), and z is not affected by x(so dz/dx=0). And I also know y is affected by x(so dy/dx!=0)

Comment: It looks like it would be a good idea for you to review what the chain rule _actually_ says instead of trying to reason about the incomplete or incorrect understanding of it that you have here.

Comment: It's **not** the case that $y$ is a **constant function** of $z$, which is what you seem to claim. (If that were the case, then you would indeed have $dy/dz=0$.) Frank's weight $y$ might change even if his father's weight $z$ remains the same, which means that $y$ **cannot** be a function of $z$. There **is no function** $f$ such that $y=f(z)$. Therefore it's **meaningless** to even **talk** about $dy/dz$.

Comment: On the other hand, you can actually view the father's weight $z$ as a function of Frank's age $x$ (at least after Frank has been born!), since that's the same as saying that $z$ is a function of time. So there is a function $z=g(x)$, but that doesn't have to be a **constant** function, since the father's weight might change during Frank's lifetime. So the idea that $dz/dx=0$ is also wrong.